# Import "tkcalendar" could not be resolved

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I am building a GUI on **TKinter** and wanted to include a calendar to pick dates. I had imported **tkcalendar** and followed he steps mentioned in its documentation to install tkcalendar.
But, it shows a problem while running the code in VSCode while importing.

`from tkcalendar import Calendar`

> Import "tkcalendar" could not be resolved

I have looked up the documentation and several other pages but couldn't resolve the error.
Please help me.

Ubuntu 20.04
No virtual env

Comment: Make sure that the Python environment used by VSCode is the one that you used to install `tkcalendar`.

Comment: @acw1668 I have taken care of that

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue in my VSCode.

Comment: Could you tell me what commands you had used to install tkcalendar?

Comment: Let us know what operating system you are working on and if you are using a virtual environment, and if so, which one?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I am not using any Virtual env

Comment: @NisargKudgunti Just run `pip install tkcalendar` in the console.  Note that `pip` should be from the same Python environment used in your VSCode.

Comment: I already did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the `VS Code` Integrated Terminal using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> shortcut and type the command `which python`. Then locate the `settings.json` file inside the `.vscode` folder of your project and specify the python interpreter path as shown below:

```
"python.pythonPath": "output_of_which_python_command"
```

Then open `VS Code` Integrated Terminal again and type the command `python -m pip freeze` to check if `tkcalendar` is actually installed. If not, then type the command `pip install tkcalendar`.